# Error wtf UnMute Command: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: 'unmute',
  async execute (client, message, args) {

  let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
  let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');

  if (!user.roles.cache.has(muteRole.id)) return message.reply("Is not Muted");
  user.roles.remove(muteRole.id);

     }
};
```

This code worked 2 weeks ago and now there is a bug, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't any Muted role. The error clearly says `Cannot find 'id' of undefined`, and the only place I see .id used is on the Muted role.

Just saying, you also need to say where the console says the error is. Just saying, "This is the error" doesn't help.

You may want to use this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'unmute',
    async execute(message, args) {
       var user_to_mute = message.mentions.user.first()
          .catch(err) {
               console.error(err)
               return message.reply("Could not find user in cache!")
          }
       var muted_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == "Muted")
          .catch(err) {
               console.error(err)
               return message.reply("Could not find role in cache!")
          }
       if (user_to_mute.has(muted_role)) return message.reply("User isn't muted!")
       user_to_mute.removeRole(muted_role).catch(console.error)
    }
};
```

Comment: `message.mentions.user.first()` and `message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == "Muted")` aren't async, so doing .catch won't work. Even if it did, that's not the correct syntax and returning inside of the catch wouldn't return from the execute function